# How to transfer your local sqlite3 data to heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, psql

I made a django which works perfect,I then tried to deploy it to heroku.Everything is great but my local data.My development db was sqlite3 than I configured heroku database url in there.The data that was stored in my sqlite3.How can I transfer local data to my heroku app which uses postgres. Please can you walk me through!

Here's my django database settings

```
The database url is the heroku postgres url
DATABASES = {
 'default':dj_database_url.config(
        default=env('DATABASE_URL')
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are few things, I would like to add to the previous answer, by which I was able to successfully migrate my data from local sqlite db to heroku's postgresql db.

First of all, dump your database into a json file, like shown below:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --exclude contenttypes > db.json
```

Once this is done, you need to commit and push this changes to local as well as heroku's git repositories. This step is needed, because we need to load the data from this "db.json" file and for that it should be present in heroku's repo. so, type these commands:

```
git add .  
git commit -m "added db"
git push
git push heroku main
```

After pushing to heroku main, you may want to run `heroku run ls` which will list all the files in the repo and make sure, your db.json is present.

Finally run this to load the data into heroku:

```
heroku run python3 manage.py loaddata db.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to use fixtures. For that, first you need to run [**`dumpdata`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata):

```
python manage.py dumpdata > db.json
```

Then commit those fixtures with your code. Then in Heroku you need to load those data using [**`loaddata`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#loaddata).

```
python manage.py loaddata db.json
```

Comment: No the data is still  not there!

Comment: you need to run dump data in your local machine, did you check if you got anything inside json?

Comment: Yeah I got this some json data but  I see nothing similar to my own data in sqlite3

Comment: Now I'm having a new problem.My sqlite3 databse which is connected locally with my django project.is not showing any data .

Comment: python manage.py dumpdata > db.json --database="db.sqlite3".It gives me this error CommandError: Unable to serialize database: The connection db.sqlite3 doesn't exist

Comment: And when I don't mention the databse I get a json file but it's not having the data which was in sqlite3.I think the problem lies in dtabase connection somehow django has got disconnected from sqlite3 and is still not showing any error

Comment: probably your command is not correct. it should be `python manage.py dumpdata --database="default" > db.json`

Comment: The database is now connected to the sqlite3 as it was before but now it's not showing any data from it

Comment: The database somehow is disconnected

Comment: try this command: `python manage.py dumpdata --all > db.json`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212138/discussion-between-ubaid-parvaiiz-and-ruddra).